Visual Studio Code debugger stoped working after migration to esm-only package ussage
Issue
My visual studio code debugger stoped working as soon as we moved our code use latest esm-only packages. After we made the changes in .swcrc and typescript config the debugger throws the error failed to get the node_modules path
Setup
My debugger setup (parts of the launch.json) is the following
{
      "name": "run api tests",
      "request": "launch",
      "type": "node",
      "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/"],
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/apps/api/node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js",
      "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/apps/api/.env.test",
      "args": ["--config", "./apps/api/jest-api.config.mjs"],
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
}

The setup in jest-api.config.mjs should be irrelevant as it only runs jest from our node_modules.
.swcrc
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/swcrc",
  "module": {
    "type": "commonjs"
  },
  "jsc": {
    "parser": {
      "syntax": "typescript",
      "dynamicImport": true,
      "tsx": false,
      "decorators": false
    },
    "experimental": {
      "plugins": [["swc_mut_cjs_exports", {}]]
    },
    "transform": { "legacyDecorator": true, "decoratorMetadata": false, "useDefineForClassFields": false },
    "target": "es2020",
    "externalHelpers": true,
    "baseUrl": "."
  },
  "sourceMaps": true
}

tsconfig.json
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "ES2020",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true, 
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "lib": ["es2020"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "importsNotUsedAsValues": "error",
    "ignoreDeprecations": "5.0",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "isolatedModules": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "storage", "package.json", "test_assets"],
  "files": ["src/types.ts"],
  "ts-node": {
    "files": true
  }
}

Error message
● Test suite failed to run

failed to get the node_modules path

  at Compiler.transformSync (../../node_modules/.pnpm/@swc+core@1.5.7_@swc+helpers@0.5.11/node_modules/@swc/core/index.js:244:29)
  at transformSync (../../node_modules/.pnpm/@swc+core@1.5.7_@swc+helpers@0.5.11/node_modules/@swc/core/index.js:351:21)
  at Object.process (../../node_modules/.pnpm/@swc+jest@0.2.36_@swc+core@1.5.7_@swc+helpers@0.5.11_/node_modules/@swc/jest/index.js:73:45)
  at ScriptTransformer.transformSource (../../node_modules/.pnpm/@jest+transform@29.7.0/node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:545:31)
  at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (../../node_modules/.pnpm/@jest+transform@29.7.0/node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:674:40)
  at ScriptTransformer.transform (../../node_modules/.pnpm/@jest+transform@29.7.0/node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:726:19)`

Side information
We use pnpm for managing multiple repositories in the same folder. This also worked before migration. Can it be that now I have to specify where to find the correct node_modules ?! I give the correct path to the jest binary so it should work.

For me installing @swc/plugin-transform-imports resolved the issue:
npm i @swc/plugin-transform-imports

